# update time values real time for comments on a page

Tags: javascript, real-time

i want to be able to update the time values of all comments on a page as in the time elapsed. 
i know that i should be running a script with `setInterval()` or may be use long polling, don't know if this is a preferred technique.

Moreover, even if i get the updated values(maybe in an array) of all comments in JS response, how am i supposed to assign the values to related comments.

If there is some other logic i should use, please suggest and help with it.

I think it would be more or less like push notification functionality.

**EDIT: ** since this has been downvoted already, but also that i have now posted the question, i would appreciate if people would suggest me something please..

**update**: I achieved the above functionality by recreating the PHP function which calculated elapsed time in JavaScript which is as follows:

```
function calcTime(date){

if(date == ""){
  return "No date provided";
}

periods = new Array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
lengths = new Array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

now = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
unix_date = date;

// check validity of date
if(unix_date == ""){
    return "bad date";
 }

// future date or past date
if(now > unix_date){
 difference = now - unix_date;
 tense = "ago";
} else {
  difference = unix_date - now;
  tense = "from now";
}

for(var j=0;difference >= lengths[j] && j < (lengths.length) - 1; j++){
difference /= lengths[j];
}
difference = Math.round(difference);

 if(difference != 1){
    periods[j] += "s";  
}

return difference+" "+periods[j]+" "+tense ;

}
```

in the HTML returned a hidden value with the timestamp from database and then looped through the results in JS to get the new values using `setInterval()` function, thereby eliminating the need to call php and unnecessary initiating ajax requests. something like this:

```
(function(){
  setInterval(function (){
  timeValues = document.getElementsByClassName('unixTime');
  abbrValues = document.getElementsByClassName('full_timestamp');
  len = timeValues.length;
  alen = abbrValues.length;

  for(i=0; i<len;i++){
 ut = timeValues[i].value;
   for(j=0;j<alen;j++){
    abbrValues[i].innerHTML = calcTime(ut);
      }
      }

   },10000);

 })();
```

Thanks everyone who tried to help and i appreciate the moderators for reopening this question.

Comment: downvote outrightly? i just needed the logic to assign the correct values to all comments.

Comment: I would believe you were down-voted because you didn't try anything, and just expect 'free code'.

Comment: I get the distinct feeling you didn't read my above comment.  Please take it to heart.. try something first, and you'll have a better response.

Comment: @Daedalus are u suggesting that i should delete this and do a bit of research and come back and post another one if i have a problem

Comment: Delete?  Perhaps, but that wasn't my suggestion.. my suggestion was to try something first, and edit your question accordingly.  Not only that, your question is rather vague as it stands.  It's difficult to give you a code tailored to your needs when we don't know what your goal is.

Comment: ok, i got you. i asked about delete as it might get further downvoted and won't become a useful question

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
          setInterval("getTime();", 30000);
     })
```

Comment: how do i assign the correct values to comments, i'm kind of confused.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're using Jquery then the comment section must have a label where you want to store the "time" so if that label has an ID ='timeid' then it would be as simple as this where response is the new time in minutes or whatever you want

```
function getTime(){
 $.ajax(){
 // get response here
 //
 $('#timeid').val(response.' minutes');

 }
 }
```

Comment: thats what my problem is. As there will be more than 1 comment, how will i update all of them in one go with every ajax request?

Comment: There's a lot of ways to do it let me think
1.Make only 1 DIV that will contain all the coments, then from ajax you get every comment with their own time and then just $('divid').html(response).
2. Make a different id for every comment and then asign the values with a FOR

I would go with number 1